# How to import ColdFusion project into Eclipse ColdFusion Builder?

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I downloaded ColdFusion project form git-hub. I have included the **ColdFusion Builder plugin into  Eclipse**. It was successfully installed. Now when I am trying to import the above downloaded project into eclipse, I am getting a message:

> no projects are found to import

How to resolve my problem?

Comment: Eclipse needs a file named `.project` in the root folder of the project.. Is there such a file?

Comment: Tanks for the reply ,I didn't any .project in the root folder of the project.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a new project pointing to the code rather than trying to import it.

Comment: Perhaps the first step is to read up on how projects work in Eclipse in general, before simply diving straight in? Especially if your next step is to ask others to help instead doing your own research into it! But @ScottStroz's advice is sound too.